# Adding theme to Seekbar programmatically makes Seekbar disappear

Tags: android, android-seekbar

I need to add a variable number of Seekbars depending on configuration.

```
for(int i=0;i<length;i++){

            seeks[i] = new SeekBar(getActivity());
            seeks[i].setMax(4);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            layoutParams.setMargins(30,30,30,30);
            seeks[i].setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            ll.addView(seeks[i]);
            seeks[i].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Works perfectly, but I would like the Seekbar to be discrete. In XML you can just add:

```
<SeekBar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar.Discrete"/>
```

However, if I follow the Docs, you should be able to add a Theme in the Seekbar constructor like so:

```
seeks[i] = new SeekBar(getActivity(), null, R.style.myTheme2 );
```

where I have set the theme in the styles.xml, OR

```
seeks[i] = new SeekBar(getActivity(), null, R.style.Widget_AppCompat_SeekBar_Discrete);
```

However, as soon as I do either of those things, the Seekbar disappears from view completely.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working, leaving up for others who have the same problem, as I couldn't find it anywhere:

First setup a layout for each individual SeekBar:

seekbar_base.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SeekBar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:progressBackgroundTint="@color/seekBarBackground"
    android:progressTint="@color/seekBarProgress"
    android:thumbTint="@color/seekBar"
    android:paddingLeft="20sp"
    android:paddingTop="3dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="30dp"
    android:theme="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar.Discrete" />
```

Then instantiate it like so:

```
SeekBar bar = (SeekBar)LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.seekbar_base, null);
```

I still have no idea why it didn't work the way the docs said it should, but oh well.

Answer (score 0):

when you use the XML, it actually set some default attribute. it is located in  `core / res / res / values / styles.xml`

```
<style name="Widget.SeekBar">
        <item name="android:indeterminateOnly">false</item>
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@android:drawable/progress_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@android:drawable/progress_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">20dip</item>
        <item name="android:maxHeight">20dip</item>
        <item name="android:thumb">@android:drawable/seek_thumb</item>
        <item name="android:thumbOffset">8dip</item>
        <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
    </style>
```

at the same time, the `SeekBar(Context context)` also use the defalut style. it relaize that by call the same method you called, but set a defalut style.

```
public SeekBar(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }
public SeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, com.android.internal.R.attr.seekBarStyle);
    }
```

so change your theme extends it.the add your custom item.

```
seeks[i] = new SeekBar(getActivity(), null, R.style.Widget_AppCompat_SeekBar_Discrete);
```

here are the document descirbe for three params constructor:

> Perform inflation from XML and apply a class-specific base style from a
>   theme attribute. This constructor of View allows subclasses to use their
>   own base style when they are inflating. For example, a Button class's
>   constructor would call this version of the super class constructor and
>   supply `R.attr.buttonStyle` for defStyleAttr; this
>   allows the theme's button style to modify all of the base view attributes
>   (in particular its background) as well as the Button class's attributes.